# Is there a way to use the 3D Views or 3D Perspective in Google Maps API?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, 3d

I am trying to use the 3D View / 3D perspective in a project. I can't find any tutorial, sample or documentation for this feature.

[Expected View](https://www.google.pt/maps/place/Quarteira/@37.0560435,-8.1223303,2676a,20y,40.99t/data=!3m1!1e3!4m5!3m4!1s0xd1ab5a60f24ad0b:0x8486f81cada03a09!8m2!3d37.0716285!4d-8.1019875?hl=en)

PS: There are a few question about showing 3D Buildings from SketchUp, that is not what I am asking.

Comment: Probably map.setTilt(tilt:number) is the method you are looking for. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Map

Comment: setTilt uses normal airplane images at 45 degree angle and not the 3D view feature

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know this isn't exactly what you're looking for but cesium.js is a pretty awesome (and I'd say more powerful) library for 3d mapping which can use the google satellite basemaps.  It supports 3d terrain but I'm having trouble finding the demo at the moment.

https://cesiumjs.org/